# Can I change the account from outside the game by editing the system files?

Tags: pc, lords-mobile

I play a game on a PC and have several accounts and if I want to switch accounts I have to do it from within the game and it's very complicated, I'm curious if I can do it from outside the game
for example, I can edit the system file which contains email and password data using notepad, so I only need to copy and paste the email and password for the account I want then save in notepad and restart the game, that will be easier and simpler.
If you want to know, I logged in using my Facebook account